# SQLite batch inserts to multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

This works fine:

```
insert into Genres (ID, Genre) 
select 1 AS ID, 'Action' AS Genre 
union select 2, 'Adventure'
```

...and this works fine:

```
insert into Movies_Genres (ID, MovieID, GenreID) 
select 1 AS ID, 2 AS MovieID, 1 AS GenreID 
union select 2, 3, 1
```

...but when I try to combine the two statements:

```
insert into Genres (ID, Genre) 
select 1 AS ID, 'Action' AS Genre 
union select 2, 'Adventure' 
insert into Movies_Genres (ID, MovieID, GenreID) 
select 1 AS ID, 2 AS MovieID, 1 AS GenreID 
union select 2, 3, 1
```

...it throws an error. I also tried separating the 2 table batches by a semicolon, but also got an error. "An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement." And "syntax error". I have a large amount of inserts to do, so I need to maximize performance, and I have found this approach very robust and fast:

[How to insert multiple rows into a SQLite 3 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038759/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-a-sqlite-3-table)

So, what is the proper syntax to batch together a bunch of inserts aimed at different tables?

Comment: Use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: How are you delivering the `INSERT` statements to the sqlite3?  If you're doing that using a method that expects a single statement, you will not be able to include both `INSERT` statements in a single submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One statement cannot insert into multiple table.

Just execute multiple statement.
(This will be fast if you use a single transaction.)

Comment: sqlite doesn't have a batch separator (such as semicolon) for multiple statements? All other DB platforms support that, so I just figured sqlite would too.

Comment: It has, but the drivers in many languages/libraries do not allow it to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: Got it working; just seems strange you can't batch up any insert you want, to any table, in the same batch.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder can you tell me please how you got it working i wanna insert into 2 tables

Comment: @TeeJay This depends on the language you're using. Ask a new question.

Comment: @CL i am using vb.net